# Excel data replication and automated saving

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replicate data entered from one worksheet into another and then have it save twice per day when complete on a separate line each time on sheet2.  I have run into a few issues.

My first issue is that I have concatenated data when pulling from the first sheet to the second from multiple cells and that data is not replicating properly but all other string columns are.

The second issue is that the automated replication of data to a new line per the timer set is not working unless that sheet is specifically selected.  The primary usage of this will be to have the sheet 1 open/updated and for sheet 2 to save the data every specified period of time but sheet 1 will always be the one open on the machine this will run on.

Here is an example of one of my concatenated lines:

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!I9,", ",Sheet1!I10,", ",Sheet1!I11,", ",Sheet1!I12)
```

The code below is what I am using to write a row on the second sheet every 5 seconds during testing.  When I switch sheets, it starts pasting the data to the active sheet.  Is it possible to specify only to output to sheet2?

```
Option Explicit
Public dTime As Date

Sub ValueStore()
Dim dTime As Date
    Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A2").Value
    Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("B2").Value
    Range("C" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("C2").Value
    Range("D" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("D2").Value
    Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("E2").Value
    Range("F" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("F2").Value
    Range("G" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("G2").Value
    Range("H" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("H2").Value
    Range("I" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("I2").Value
    Range("J" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("J2").Value




  Call StartTimer1
End Sub


Sub StartTimer1()
    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer1()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

This is the code I am using for the buttons to start and stop this:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call StartTimer1
    End Sub

    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Call StopTimer1
    End Sub
```

### Update

To clarify further, the strings I am concatenating into a single cell are showing up blank when copying the row repeatedly every 5 seconds but the other cells that are not concatenated will copy without issue.

Comment: If you have a clarification to make, while it is excellent to update the question, do also comment under the answer that requests the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (adjust sheet names as required)

**EDITED** - prevent issues with no content on ColA

```
Sub ValueStore()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Value = Now 'put a timestamp in first cell
        'then copy the values
        .Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 10).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Resize(1, 10).Value
    End With

    StartTimer1

End Sub
```

I'm not following your concatenation problem.

Comment: To clarify further, the strings I am concatenating into a single cell are showing up blank when copying the row repeatedly every 5 seconds but the other cells that are not concatenated will copy without issue.

Comment: Exactly where are your concatenation formulas entered?  Is calculation set to automatic?

Comment: I enter them on Sheet2 pulling the data from multiple cells on Sheet1.  An example is =CONCATENATE(Sheet1!I9,", ",Sheet1!I10,", ",Sheet1!I11,", ",Sheet1!I12)

Comment: Where on sheet2 ?

Comment: cells AB-AI are concatenated data on sheet2 pulling from cells on sheet1 and those do not duplicate on the next line but all the regular ones do.

Comment: In your original question you're only copying Col A to Col I

Comment: I left the second half of the code out to try to simplify my questions as it was redundant of those lines.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, i got the concatenated data issue solved but am still having issues with it replicating data to sheet 2 while i am looking at sheet 1.  Please let me know if you have any more ideas and i really appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "issues" ?

Comment: In the example you provided, it is copying data from F2 on Sheet1 to F11 on Sheet2 but not replicating on a new line each time it is copied. (every 5 seconds)

Comment: This: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` relies on there always being content in the first column (ie. Something must get copied to ColA)  If that's not the case then a different approach is needed.

Comment: Thank you again for your help Tim, I really appreciate it.  The data is being pulled from all over the place on Sheet 1 and i need the combination of data to always write to a new row on Sheet2 with the data in a specific order.  Do you have a code template i could use to accomplish this?  It's also important that i be able to always view sheet 1 while sheet 2 is being updated.

Comment: So my edit didn't fix the problem?  I'm not sure why it wouldn't...   There's no "code template" - what I wrote in my answer is how I'd do it: if that's not working then there's something specific going on in your case which is unexpected or you haven't told us about.

Comment: Hi Tim.  The modified code is working properly as it is written but i need it to only pull certain cells rather than the entire row.  On Row 2 of Sheet1, it is pulling F2,G2,I2 and J2 and duplicating it to sheet2 but i need it to only pull G2 and J2, however the cells will vary per row as far as which cells need to be pulled (i am duplicating around 30 rows of unique cells from sheet 1 that vary as far as which cells i will need to pull per row and copy to specific cells in the second spreadsheet by the time i am done with this project) .

Comment: By template i meant a general format where i can copy the line a few times and alter which cells it will duplicate.  Thank you again for all of your help, much appreciated!

Comment: "i am duplicating around 30 rows of unique cells from sheet 1" - that wasn't clear at all from your original question.  At this point it would be useful to create a new question which addresses your actual use case: don't simplify your actual problem to the point where it looks like a different problem altogether.